# Comparing a NumPy array to another

Tags: numpy

I have 2 NumPy arrays, such as:

```
correct   = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
predicted = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2])
```

I would like to create 2 new arrays, which contain the indices of 1's incorrectly predicted as something else and the indices of 2's incorrectly predicted as something else, respectively. Desired result:

```
incorrect_ones = [2]
incorrect_twos = [5, 8]
```

There just has to be some NumPy way to achieve this... Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the boolean conditions and find the indexes of the locations of the `True` values:

```
np.where((correct == 1) & (predicted == 2))[0]
# array([2])
np.where((correct == 2) & (predicted == 1))[0]
# array([5, 8])
```